# Have a realistic viewport?

Tags: interface

While I'm modeling, I would like to have a realistic viewport instead of the default aspect. How can I achieve this?

There are any options in Blender or should I download an addon?

Comment: What do you mean by realistic? Do you mean you wish to have a rendered viewport? And in which render mode are you, Blender Internal or Cycles?

Comment: Cycles. 
I dont mean a rendered viewport, I mean while I'm modeling

Comment: As this: https://gyazo.com/245cb6d4ed01acda72b3a559ad58c620

Answer (score 3):

You could use "Matcap". Just open the Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) and activate matcap. You then can select a preset. Some of them look pretty nice.

You could also use the add-on "Quick Preferences". It gives you some nice presets for your viewport lightning (the way you model is lit in the viewport). Hope it helps :)

Btw, there are ways to render objects far prettier then Blenders viewport does (like in Quixel suite for example), but that's not the case for Blender.

There's however a guy who created/creates a glsl viewport in Blender. His threat (pretty awesome stuff!):

http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343278-GLSL-PBR-Shader-for-viewport